# Why can't virtualbox host network be same as host network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I was remotely connecting to the Ubuntu PC(10.100.x.x) and this Host implemented a virtualbox vm(192.168.55.x).

When I change the vm's (host-only)network same as Host PC's.(10.100.x.x)
Then my remote connection is stop, and I can't access the remote Ubuntu host any more.

Why VM's host network can't get network same as Host's?

I'm not english user and, new for networking.
Please help me and, I appreciate your kindness in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the settings in virtual box ?
As far as I know you can select if the VM should be in the same network as the host or not. Basically it will simulate a pyhsically separated network if you don´t

Comment: Which settings I have to check? I meant that whether the vm's host-only interface network can be same as Host's network. Because when different network, I was able to remote access to Host PC, but after same network, it could not.

Comment: There should be an option called "network bridge" or similar.
Try this one, it will put your machine into the same network as the host.
You might have to set the IP on the machine or enable DHCP if there´s a DHCP server in your network (in private networks usually the router)